# can i update the private static dateTime each time the task runs (C# - quartz-scheduler)

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, quartz.net

I have set DateTime to return the current time which works fine, but due to the requirement of having a private static inside(it's scheduled Job - I am using quartz-scheduler) the main class, when the program runs for the first time i get the correct DateTime however as you know it's static field each time after the first time i get the same old value of the DateTime.

my question is, is there's any way to get the new DateTime each time the program runs?

`private static DateTime currentDateTime= DateTime.Today;`

Thanks.

UPDATE

As i was making HTTP WEB REQUEST, the currentDateTime was cached after the first run so I had to caching policy for the request using

```
HttpRequestCachePolicy noCachePolicy = new HttpRequestCachePolicy(HttpRequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);
webRequest.CachePolicy = noCachePolicy;
```

Comment: `DateTime.Today` is a public static property anyway; why do you need to access it via another static property?

Comment: because I am using quartz scheduler and everything is set to private

Answer (score 3):

As i understand the issue is that you are setting the value one. Why don't you try to make it property and then when you try to get the data do

```
  private static DateTime currentDateTime{
  get
  { 
   return DateTime.Today;
  }
 }
```

Comment: you are a star.

Thank you, this is what i was trying to do, at the moment i was able to get it running on my local machine, once it work on the server as well i will let you know.

Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Stick a `>` there are you are good.

```
private static DateTime currentDateTime=> DateTime.Today;
```

Comment: Thank you.
this solution did work for me as the other solution.

Comment: Yes, both are the same thing just syntactically different.

Comment: I have used your solution as it was easier to implement and i didn't require me to add more lines of code.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Out of curiosity, you have some very weird metrics to measure subjective attributes of the code. Why? The comment on your question is something I also want to know. Why give an alias to DateTime.Now? Then you mention it is less LoC, but that is just syntactic sugar and does not change meaning in any way.